# one-one and onto proofs

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $f$ takes the $[-1,1]$ onto $[-1,1]$, then 
$$f^{-1}(f(\{ 0 \})) = \{ 0 \}$$

*Proof :* Let the domain $= X$ which is the set $[-1,1]$ Let the co-domain $=Y$ which is the set $[-1,1]$.

$f$ onto implies that there exists an inverse function $g: Y \to X$ called the inverse S.T. $g(f(x))= x$ and $f(g(y))=y$. Since $0 \in X$ and $0 \in Y$ it follows directly that $g(f(0))=0$ and $f(g(y))=y$ which proves the claim.

Let $X,Y$ be sets and $f: X \to Y$. Prove that :

$$f(A\setminus B) = f(A)\setminus f(B)$$

TO be honest I am not even sure what this question is asking. It is very hard to imagine functions as cartesian products..

Comment: If the function is **only** onto then this need not be true. Moreover just the ontoness doesn't guarantee the existence of the inverse of the function. So are you given that $f$ is one-one as well?

Comment: $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ satisfies the hypothesis but not the conclusion

Comment: In the second question what are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: The second question is true if $f$ is one-to-one, but it might not be if $f$ isn't one-to-one

Comment: "It is very hard to imagine functions as cartesian products.." they aren't asking you  to (although in other lessons the will ask you to think of functions as subsets of cartesian product but that has nothing to do with this question).  Here all they are asking you to think of is the function mapping SETS of points into SETS of points and think about what sets certain sets are mapped from.

Comment: A second question just came to mind. With a lot of elementary functions you can take the inverse and plug into the function and y to show that it is onto. If that's not the case how else do you prove its onto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> f onto implies that there exists an inverse function

No.

Consider $f:\mathbb R \to [0, \infty)$ via  $f(x) = x^2$ or $g:\mathbb R \to [-1,1]$ via $f(x) = \sin x$.  These functions are onto but they are not one-to-one.  For any $f(x) = y$ there maybe *two* solutions to $x$ (if $x$ is a solution so is $-x$) and $\sqrt{x}$ is *not* an inverse function.  And if $g(x)  =y$ there will be *infinitely* many solutions (if $x$ is a solution, then so is $x + k2\pi$).  $\arcsin x$ is *not* an inverse function.

I realize mathematicians are not consistant with notation and that is *their* fault, not yours. but $f^{-1}(A)$ does not mean an inverse function but .... if $f:X\to Y$ and $A\subset Y$ then $f^{-1}(A)$ means all the elements of $X$ that get mapped do any element of $A$.

Example if $f(x) = x^2$ then $f^{-1}(\{16\}) = \{4,-4\}$ because $4$ and $-4$ are the elements so that $f(x) = 16$.  And $f^{-1}(\{16,25\}) = \{4,-4,5,-5\}$ because those are the elements that get mapped to $16$ or $25$.

And $f^{-1}(\{-2\}) = \emptyset$ as nothing gets mapped to $-2$.  And $f^{-1}(\{-2, -25, 3, 49\}) = \{\sqrt 3,-\sqrt{3}, 7, -7\}$ because those are all the elements that get mapped to $-2,-25, 3,$ or $49$.

....

So your question.

$f$ being onto means there is $x\in [-1,1]$ so that $f(x) =0$.  There may be many of them.  There may be an infinite number of them.  But ther is one.  So $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is not the empty set.

Now by *definition*  $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{x\in [-1,1]| f(x) = 0\}$.

And be *definition* $f(A) = \{f(x)|x\in A\}$.

So.......

$f(f^{-1}(\{0\})) = f(\{x\in [-1,1]|f(x)=0\}) =$

$\{f(x)|x \in \{x\in[-1,1]|f(x)=0\}\}$

..... well if $x\in \{x\in[-1,1]|f(x)=0\}$ then that means $f(x) = 0$.

So $\{f(x)|x \in \{x\in[-1,1]|f(x)=0\}\}=$

$\{0\}$.

And that is it.

Comment: When you say $f(y)$ do you mean the inverse? Just trying to be clear as possible

Comment: Oh that represents the codomain of f right?

Comment: When I said $f(y)$ I meant there was a $y$ in the domain and I am mapping it to $0$.  Would it have been easier if I called it $x$.  The labels don't matter.  But *no* I did *not* mean the inverse.  $f$ doesn't *have* an inverse.

Comment: Im doing this on my phone so it may look off. Yes I was a little confused by the notation and we can say it maps zero because it is in the co-domain I presume. So the definitions of $f^(-1)(0) is a set containing an element x in the domain that maps f(x)=0. I think I am mixing something up

Comment: What is $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Everything else makes perfect sense

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ then $f^{-1}$ is notation for the reverse or inverse mapping so that for a set $A\subset Y$ then $f^{-1}(A)$ is the set of all the $x\in X$ so that $f(x) \in A$.  So if $f(7)=0;f(2)=0; f(\pi)=0$ and no other $f(x)=0$ then $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ are ll the $x$ so that $f(x)=0$.  So $f^{-1}(\{0\}) =\{7,2,\pi\}$.  The thing is $f^{-1}$ doesn't have to be a function as for any single vale a $f^{-1}(a)$ could be multiple values.  If the function is one-to-one it is invertible so $f^{-1}$ could refer to the inverse function.

Answer (score 0):

As to the second question.

If $X$ is a set then $f(X) = \{f(x)|x \in X\}$

So $f(A\setminus B) = \{f(x)| x \in A$ but $x\not \in B\}$.

And $f(A)\setminus f(B) = \{f(x)|x \in A\}\setminus \{f(x)|x\in B\}=$

Now the statement that $f(A\setminus B) = f(A)\setminus f(B)$ is *not* true.  It is true if $f$ is one-to-one but it is not true in general.

If $w \in f(A\setminus B)$ then there is an $x\in A\setminus B$, that is that $x \in A$ but $x \not \in B$ so that $f(x) = w$.

So $w \in f(A)$ because $w = f(x)$.  Now $x \not \in B$ but there may or may not be a $y\in B$ so that $f(y) =w$ as well.  If there is, then $w \in F(B)$.  If there isn't then $w\not \in f(B)$.  If $f$ is one-to -on then there isn't any but if $f$ isn't one-to-one there might be.

So it might be that $w \in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ or it might be $w \not \in f(A)\setminus f(B)$.  If $w \not \in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ then $f(A\setminus B)\ne f(A)\setminus f(B)$.

But if $f$ is one-to-one then $w$ *can't* be in $f(B)$ because $x\in A\setminus B$ is the *only* solution to $f(x)=w$.  This is true for all $w\in f(A\setminus B)$ so $f(A\setminus B)\subset f(A)\setminus f(B)$.  *IF* $f$ is one-to-one.

On the other hand if $w \in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ then $w \in F(A)$ and $w \not \in F(B)$.  So there is an $x \in A$ so that $w = f(x)$.  And there are absolutely no $y\in B$ so that $f(y) =w$.  So the $x\in A$ can not be in $B$.  So $x \in A\setminus B$.  And $f(x) =w$ so $w\in f(A\setminus B)$.  That is true for all $w \in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ so $f(A)\setminus f(B)\subset f(A\setminus B)$.

This is true of all functions.

So if $f$ is one-to-one this is true as mutual subsets are equal.  But if $f$ is not one to one it might not be true as its possible for $f(x) =f(y) = w$ where $x \in A\setminus B$ and $y \in B$.